# Find an $v,w \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $(1+2i)v=1-i$ and $w^{2}-i=0$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

Task from an old exam:

> Find an $v,w \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $(1+2i)v=1-i$ and $w^{2}-i=0$
>   and write the solutions in this form: $a+bi$

I'm currently trying to solve this, probably written several pages and always failed calculating it with success so I came here. I think there is some info missing for this task, about definition but anyway maybe you can give me some ideas of how this could be solved?

Comment: It helped if you showed where exactly you got stuck. Hint for the first: $v=(1-i)/(1+2i)$.

Comment: That's what I tried too, then also tried using third binomial formula but nothing..

Comment: Don't know what's the "*third binomial formula*" or how it would apply here. Just multiply both the numerator and denominator by the conjugate of the latter, then expand the products and collect $\frac{(1-i)(1-2i)}{(1+2i)(1-2i)}$.

Comment: $$v=\frac{1-2i-i+2i^{2}}{1-2i+2i+4i^{2}}=\frac{2i^{2}-3i+1}{-4i^{2}+1}$$

Comment: Now $i^2=-1$ so $\cdots$

Comment: $$v=\frac{1-3i-2}{1+4}=\frac{-1-3i}{5}$$ But what now or am I going wrong? :s

Comment: That's the answer to the first part of the question: $$v = \frac{-1}{5} + \frac{-3}{5}\,i$$ For the second part, either take the square root of $i$ if you are familiar with complex roots, or write $w=a+bi$, substitute in $w^2-i=0$, then equate the real and imaginary parts to $0$ to determine $a,b$.

Comment: Alright thanks a lot! <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We obtain from $(1+2i)v=1-i$
>
> \begin{align*}
> v&=\frac{1-i}{1+2i}\\
> &=\frac{(1-i)(1-2i)}{(1+2i)(1-2i)}\\
> &=\frac{-1-3i}{5}\\
> &=-\frac{1}{5}-\frac{3}{5}i
> \end{align*}

We recall
\begin{align*}
w^2&=a+ib\\
&=r\left(\cos\phi+i\sin \phi\right)\\
w_{1,2}&=\pm\sqrt{r}\left(\cos\frac{\phi}{2}+i\sin \frac{\phi}{2}\right)\\
\end{align*}

> We obtain from $w^2-i=0$
>
> \begin{align*}
> w^2&=i\\
> &=1\left(\cos \frac{\pi}{2}+i\sin \frac{\pi}{2}\right)\\
> \\
> w_{1,2}&=\pm\sqrt{1}\left(\cos \frac{\pi}{4}+i\sin \frac{\pi}{4}\right)\\
> &=\pm\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)
> \end{align*}